# Converting a makefile to an Xcode project

Tags: xcode, gcc, command-line, makefile

So here's my dilemma.  I am familiar with compiling programs from makefiles on the command line.  I am more than familiar with compiling programs in Xcode.  My question is - Is there a straightforward process for converting a makefile to an Xcode project?

Just to be clear, I know how to build an Xcode project with an external target.  This is not what I am looking to do.

I want to add this to be a little more clear.  I am porting a game written in C++ utilizing libSDL to iOS 3.2.  I, therefore, have no choice but to convert the makefile to an Xcode project.

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [cmake](http://www.cmake.org/) ? I haven't used it myself but apparently it can generate Xcode project files.

Comment: I have.  This may end up being the direction that I take.  However, the cmake -G Xcode command which generates an Xcode project requires a CmakeLists.txt file.  For the project that I am undertaking, writing this file might be just as difficult or not more so than converting the project manually for Xcode.

Comment: Personally I use the legacy makefile method for projects with existing makefiles. If you drag the source directory into the project then you still get the benefits of the IDE and source level debugging etc. It's not perfect but for me at least it has a good cost/benefit ratio.

Answer (score 0):

Except for using the "External Build System" project template (which sounds like not what you want), there is no Makefile import tool in Xcode. What features are you missing by using an external target, however? You can still use Xcode, of course. You won't be able to use the build settings UI, but you claim to be comfortable enough with Make to not need it.